# python: check if an numpy array contains any element of another array

Tags: python, numpy

What is the best way to check if an numpy array contains any element of another array?

example:

```
array1 = [10,5,4,13,10,1,1,22,7,3,15,9]
array2 = [3,4,9,10,13,15,16,18,19,20,21,22,23]`
```

I want to get a `True` if `array1` contains any value of `array2`, otherwise a `False`.

Comment: Use `np.any(np.in1d(array2, array1))`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using Pandas, you can use `isin`:

```
a1 = np.array([10,5,4,13,10,1,1,22,7,3,15,9])
a2 = np.array([3,4,9,10,13,15,16,18,19,20,21,22,23])

>>> pd.Series(a1).isin(a2).any()
True
```

And using the [in1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html#numpy.in1d) numpy function(per the comment from @Norman):

```
>>> np.any(np.in1d(a1, a2))
True
```

For small arrays such as those in this example, the solution using set is the clear winner.  For larger, dissimilar arrays (i.e. no overlap), the Pandas and Numpy solutions are faster.  However, [`np.intersect1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) appears to excel for larger arrays.

**Small arrays (12-13 elements)**

```
%timeit set(array1) & set(array2)
The slowest run took 4.22 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.69 µs per loop

%timeit any(i in a1 for i in a2)
The slowest run took 12.29 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.88 µs per loop

%timeit np.intersect1d(a1, a2)
The slowest run took 10.29 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.6 µs per loop

%timeit np.any(np.in1d(a1, a2))
10000 loops, best of 3: 27.1 µs per loop

%timeit pd.Series(a1).isin(a2).any()
10000 loops, best of 3: 135 µs per loop
```

**Using an array with 100k elements (no overlap)**:

```
a3 = np.random.randint(0, 100000, 100000)
a4 = a3 + 100000

%timeit np.intersect1d(a3, a4)
100 loops, best of 3: 13.8 ms per loop    

%timeit pd.Series(a3).isin(a4).any()
100 loops, best of 3: 18.3 ms per loop

%timeit np.any(np.in1d(a3, a4))
100 loops, best of 3: 18.4 ms per loop

%timeit set(a3) & set(a4)
10 loops, best of 3: 23.6 ms per loop

%timeit any(i in a3 for i in a4)
1 loops, best of 3: 34.5 s per loop
```

Comment: I had the arrays swapped in my comment. I corrected it.

Comment: @Norman Does the order matter?  If we are testing to check whether they share a single value, I wouldn't think so.

Comment: Oh yeah right it's late :-) One might put the shorter array first for performance reasons, though.

Comment: And what about `np.intersect1d`? I just found it.

Answer (score 9):

You can try this

```
>>> array1 = [10,5,4,13,10,1,1,22,7,3,15,9]
>>> array2 = [3,4,9,10,13,15,16,18,19,20,21,22,23]
>>> set(array1) & set(array2)
set([3, 4, 9, 10, 13, 15, 22])
```

If you get result means there are common elements in both array.

If result is empty means no common elements.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `any` built-in function and list comprehension:

```
>>> array1 = [10,5,4,13,10,1,1,22,7,3,15,9]
>>> array2 = [3,4,9,10,13,15,16,18,19,20,21,22,23]
>>> any(i in array2 for i in array1)
True
```